# API error when testing Win Phone 8 App for the Store

Tags: api, windows-phone-8, dll

[image]

I get this error when testing my Win Phone 8 app for the store.

I can't find much information about solving it or even what it means. The app runs perfectly in debug and release.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You or some subroutine is calling `CreateMutexExA()` somewhere, which you can't use on WP. If it's in your code, you can call `CreateMutexExW()` instead. If not, you're stuck looking for another library for that functionality. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms682418%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more information on which calls can be made on WP.